# Passing parameters to a function -- push or registers

Tags: function, assembly, x86, x86-64, calling-convention

I want to write a function that does something like:

```
def addme(x, y):
    return x + y
```

I know there is already an instruction for this, but I'm practicing how to pass args in a function. What would be the proper way to pass args? I have seen something like:

```
# addme(5,2)
push $2
push $5
call addme
add $16, %rsp
```

Is this the correct way to pass in args, by pushing them to the `stack` in reverse order and then  after doing the function call resetting the stack pointer? I have also heard that the parameters are passed in `%rdi, %rsi, ...`. Is one correct and the other is incorrect, or what is the proper way to do this?

Comment: What operating system are you programming for?  The calling convention depends on that.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this the correct way to pass in args ...

This depends on the **calling convention**:

For 64-bit x86 Windows programs the arguments are passed in registers `rcx`, `rdx`, `r8` and `r9`.

And for 64-bit x86 Linux programs the registers `rdi`, `rsi`, `rcx`, `rdx`, `r8` and `r9` are used.

However, especially in 16-bit DOS and Windows but also in 32-bit Windows it was common to mix up different calling conventions.

This is still possible in 64-bit Windows or Linux:

If you write your own compiler or if you write your program completely in assembly language, you can decide to use a different calling convention for certain functions - for example passing all arguments on the stack instead of registers if the function name begins with `onstk_`.

If I understand your example correctly, you don't use C or C++ but some language like Python.

I know that some programming languages (like Java or Matlab; I don't know about Python) use a completely different calling convention when "native" (compiled or assembly) code is called. So *maybe* you'll have to pass the arguments in a completely different way.

Comment: thanks, could you please provide a link to learn more about the 64-bit Linux calling convention?

Comment: @carl.hiass It is described in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI). Because the calling convention is not only used in Linux, it is not named "Linux calling convention".